# Filling ising model with basis

Tags: ising-model, lattice-model

This questions involves how to fill a lattice with ordered basis:

Is there some established mathematical approach in filling a physical lattice with some colored basis (black and white here)? For example, a triangular lattice can be filled with 
[image: basis] to get[image: filling]

While [image] alone cannot give any filled colored graph. Is there any general systematic mathematical approach in solving this problem?